# Issue with displaying the Jquery Ajax result

Tags: php, ajax

I just need to display names of the array using `ajax`. Following code is working but the result ( Nilantha Ruwan Nimal Shamitha Alex) is just display and disappears.

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:50px";>
    <form >
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name....">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-success" id="btn">Enter</button>
    </div>
    </form> 
    <div class="msg"></div>     
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    $.post("ajax.php",{ajax_name:name},function(response){
    $(".msg").html(response);
    })
    .fail(function(error){
    alert(error.statusText);
        })
      })
    })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['ajax_name'])){
    $store = array("Nilantha","Ruwan","Nimal","Shamitha","Alex");
    foreach($store as $names) {
    echo $names,"<br>";
     }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Please try my answer it may help you.

Comment: If still getting error feel free to share your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit() {
            jQuery("form").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var name = jQuery("#name").val();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    data: {ajax_name:name},
                    success: function(response) {
                        jQuery(".msg").html(response);
                        jQuery('#name').val('');
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("Something wrong");
      }
    });});
        }

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            submit();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you. it worked,

Do you have any idea why my code didn't work?
i got it from a video tuttorial it shows that code works.

any way thanks for response

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the network tab of Chrome Devtools and ensuring that the AJAX call isn't running twice. I would think that if the query ran twice but the second one did not have any name attached then it would return blank once the first one had received its response.